# Vue.js label for an input element inside loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

How would you set up the input `id` and the label `for` on repeated input elements so they are unique, using Vue.js v2.

```
<section class="section" v-for="(section, i) in sections">

    <div class="fields">
        <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" id="" name="example-a" v-model="section.ex-a">
            <label for="">Example A</label>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="">Example B</label>
            <input type="text" id="" name="example-b" v-model="section.ex-b">
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <label for="">Example C</label>
            <input type="text" id="" name="example-c" v-model="section.ex-c">
        </fieldset>
    </div>

</section>
```

I want to be able to click on the label element and have it select the input field.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `:id=""` and `:for=""`. You would need to add a `js` string interpolation to create a unique id from the section and index information. For example:

```
<div class="fields">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" :id="'section'+i+'example-a'" name="example-a" v-model="section.ex-a">
        <label :for="'section'+i+'example-a'">Example A</label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="'section'+i+'example-b'">Example B</label>
        <input type="text" :id="'section'+i+'example-b'" name="example-b" v-model="section.ex-b">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label :for="'section'+i+'example-c'">Example C</label>
        <input type="text" :id="'section'+i+'example-c'" name="example-c" v-model="section.ex-c">
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

For example, for the first `fieldset` the binding `:id="'section'+i+'example-a'"` will render `id="section-0-example-a"` as its interpolating `'section' + the index of the array + 'example-a'`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Didn't realize you could add interpolation inside those tags.

Comment: No worries! You can as long as you use the `:id` notation, and you can also add bindings to values in your "view model"